Fatal error: apply_filters() conflict in email Customizer plugin
I use a plugin Woocommerce Email Customizer but recently the email refused to work giving PHP Error email cannot display
1
/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-email-control/ec-email-control.php(1059): apply_filters()

2
/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-email-control/ec-email-control.php(1005): WC_Email_Control->ec_style_inline_for_old_wc()

3
/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-email-control/pages/ec-preview-page.php(195): apply_filters()

4
/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-email-control/ec-email-control.php(562): require_once('/*/*/...')

How do I tackle this and what does this error mean
There's no more support for this plugin or update as a developer is gone!
I have tried to rewrite the hook function but it just seems I'm not getting it

The log above is not sufficient to identify the exact cause. You may want to consider updating the plugin if it's not up to date, and also check the version of the WooCommerce plugin. Alternatively, you can provide a more detailed log to help identify the cause.

That update in itself is how I don't know what to do, the main developer is gone and there's no way to ask for update. The two major file giving this error is in my https://github.com/afije/customise

What other information do I need to find the exact root cause?
